# Can't read files in directory on Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Anybody, please help! Want to take all file paths with .mp3 extension from directory. Is code below right to take directory path as "/storage/emulated/0/Music"?

```
class Player
{
    static readonly DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMusic).AbsolutePath));
    static readonly FileInfo[] fileLinks = FilesFromDirectory(directory);

    static FileInfo[] FilesFromDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        FileInfo[] fileLinks = new FileInfo[] { };

        if (Directory.Exists(directory.ToString()))
        {
            fileLinks = directory.GetFiles(@"*.mp3");
        }

        return fileLinks;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly , make sure that you had added permission to AndroidManifest.xml . For get the list of files with specific extension you could check Leo's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727368/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-with-specific-extension-in-xamarin-android

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media